# Expanding $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ using binomial theorem

Tags: real-analysis

This is part of proof of theorem 3.31 of baby Rudin p.64, which proves 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e.$$

Rudin put $t_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ and directly stated that by binomial theorem,

$$t_n= 1+1+\frac{1}{2!}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)+\frac{1}{3!}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)+\dots+\frac{1}{n!}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)\dots\left(1-\frac{n-1}{n}\right).$$

And I don't see why this is correct. Doesn't the binomial theorem apply like this?
$$t_n=1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2!}\frac{1}{n^2}+\dots+\frac{1}{n!}\frac{1}{n^n}$$

This expansion also makes $t_n\leq s_n$ where $s_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}$ as Rudin intended to do. And here we got $\limsup_{n\to\infty}t_n\leq e$ and from another argument we get the other inequality to finisih the proof. In that argument Rudin uses the same expansion also, but I think the result doesn't change with the normal expansion since he fixed $m$ such that $n\geq m$ and expanded $t_n$ only upto $m$, to get the lower bound of $t_n$ and took the limit with respect to $n$, and it makes the lower bound $s_m$. Then he let $m\to\infty$ and the theorem follows.

I don't know how Rudin expands the terms like that and why he did it, not using the normal expansion.

Comment: "Doesn't the binomial theorem apply like this?" No, it doesn't. When you actually do it, you get the formula stated by Rudin.

Comment: I think you forgot the binomial coefficients.

Comment: You look to be using part of the formula for $e^{\frac 1n}$ rather than the binomial expansion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You did not expand correctly.

Expanding $(1+x)^n$:
$$
(1+x)^n=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}jx^j
$$
and substituting $x=\frac1n$ gives
\begin{align*}
t_n&=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}j\frac1{n^j}\\
&=1+n\times\frac1n+\frac{n(n-1)}{2!}\frac1{n^2}+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}\frac1{n^3}+\dots+\frac{n(n-1)\times\dots\times(n-(n-1))}{n!}\frac1{n^n}\\
&=1+1+\frac1{2!}\left(1-\frac1n\right)+\frac1{3!}\left(1-\frac1n\right)\left(1-\frac2n\right)+\dots+\frac1{n!}\left(1-\frac1n\right)\dots\left(1-\frac{n-1}n\right).
\end{align*}